# How to forbid Mathematica to expand the section if launching it by tags?

Tags: cells, styling

Consider some section in a notebook tagged as "Evaluation". We want to launch it in e.g. the following way:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
NotebookFind[nb, "Evaluation", All, CellTags];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
```

The command automatically expands the cells in the section. Could you please tell me how to forbid Mathematica from expanding the content of the section with this specific tag?